# How to QR-scan image from gallery or Base64 data?

Tags: qr-code, react-native, react-native-ios

As the question indicates, how can I take a image into account and scan it using QR scanner, Image is received form backend, practically i can return the image in any format to my app, So i thought i will send the image in base64, But question arises, is how to covert that image in any way to make it possible to QR scan it,

So i break down it into two parts,

1. Saving the received image.
2. Taking that image and QR scan it.

Searched a lot but all the libraries are pointing towards scanning the QR using camera.

How can I achieve this two parts, Basically am asking for suggestions,

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.